# Error while mapping .tsv file data with Azure data warehouse using data factory

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I wanted to copy data from form data lake present in **.tsv** file to Azure data warehouse but there are 2 columns that are in **date** datatype and because of that I am facing issues while mapping the columns. And because of that I am not able to load the data. I can use u-SQL activity only if needed.

Comment: Can you show us some of the data in your tsv file? Azure SQL data warehouse support `date` datatype, please check if the date string in your tsv file is correctly? Please reference [Supported string literal formats for date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#supported-string-literal-formats-for-date)

Comment: In .tsv the column is in string data is like "20100101" and I want to map this column with data warehouse table having a datatype date

Comment: Do your error message same with me? 'Message=Column '\t'dd'' contains an invalid value '\t'20100101''. Cannot convert '\t'20100101'' to type 'DateTime'.' You can edit your problem and give more details with screenshots.

Comment: yes I am getting the same error but I have tried to convert the column into date-time using u-SQL activity after that I am getting the date like "1900-01-01T00:00:00.0000000" so actually it was like 19000101 but now even after that I am not able to do map the column and load this. Also, I want the date to be like "1900-01-01" but I am getting this in datetime2 format.

Comment: Please see my answer, you can follow my step to solve the error.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: @gauravmodi: are you familiar with accepting answers here?

Comment: While it is not mandatory to accept, vote, or comment reply to answers, it is a very good way to use the Stack Overflow platform. This is a community, and thus using the communication tools as designed helps members of the community reward and thank each other for the volunteer effort they have expended.

Comment: Moreover, I notice that your questions tend to be very short, and there is usually no record of what you have tried. Mostly you are not getting upvoted, and sometimes you get downvotes. I would guess that, over the long term, most of your questions will be put on hold, and an automatic question ban will be applied. I would therefore advise you to show what you have tried in each question, by researching the topic independently _before_ asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

I tried and tested, always get the error message:

```
"ErrorCode=UserErrorInvalidDataValue,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,
Message=Column 'dd' contains an invalid value '20190101'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ServiceLibrary,''Type=System.ArgumentException,Message=String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.Couldn't store <20190101> in dd Column.  Expected type is DateTime.,Source=System.Data,''Type=System.FormatException,Message=String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.,Source=mscorlib,'",
        "failureType": "UserError",
        "target": "Copy_b70"
```

If you don't want to change your tsv file,  I suggest you to using the Data Flow Derived Column. It can help covert the "20100101" data to a correct date format.

**Derived Column**:

[image]

Using this Expression for field Column "20100101":

```
   add( (substring(Column_2, 1, 4)),'-')+
   add((substring(Column_2, 5, 2)), '-')+
   substring(Column_2, 7, 2)
```

[image]

It works ok.

[image]

Hope this helps.